# openssl does not load engine from config file

Tags: openssl, load, config

I'm using openssl-1.0.1f. And I'm trying load pkcs11 engine from config file, but it not load module. here are my config

```
openssl_conf = openssl_def

[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
pkcs11 = pkcs11_section

[pkcs11_section]
engine_id = pkcs11
dynamic_path = /usr/lib/ssl/engines/engine_pkcs11.so
MODULE_PATH = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/opensc-pkcs11.so
default_algorithms = ALL
init = 0
```

Here are result from command ***openssl engine pkcs11 -t***

```
1996159072:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libpkcs11.so): /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libpkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
1996159072:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
1996159072:error:260B6084:engine routines:DYNAMIC_LOAD:dso not found:eng_dyn.c:447:
1996159072:error:2606A074:engine routines:ENGINE_by_id:no such engine:eng_list.c:418:id=pkcs11
```

Comment: I added my config before [req] section and then openssl loaded engine but it is unable to load module.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Ok, understood, thanks you

Comment: Hello @NguyenTienHuy, did you find solution for this? I have similar problem.